# PHP - URL to array

Tags: php, url

Suppose I have the URL look like: http://www.example.com/category/product/htc/desire, I used `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get /category/product/htc/desire, how can I convert this "/category/product/htc/desire" to array like:

```
array
(
[0] => category
[1] => product
....
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
```

Comment: This method also has the benefit of removing trailing and preceding slashes.

Answer (score 1):

use explode function

```
$list = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$url  = "/category/product/htc/desire";
$pieces = explode("/", substr($url,1));

print_r($pieces);

?>
```

obviously $url would be the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

output, see here: http://codepad.org/lIRZNTBI

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PHP strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function
You can do something like that :

```
$string = "/category/product/htc/desire";
$arr = aray();
$tok = strtok($string, "/");

while ($tok !== false) {
    arr[]= $tok:
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
```

Comment: actually, explode would be a better solution =)